# best apache configuration for developer on laptop 

Tags: apache-2.2, memory

I'm developing sites in php, I dont need many apache's and bleeding edge configuration to support thousand people, because I have only say 10 people's power.

```
 <IfModule mpm_prefork_module>  
  StartServers          1  
  MinSpareServers       1  
  MaxSpareServers       1  
  MaxClients          150  
  MaxRequestsPerChild   0  
</IfModule>  


<IfModule mpm_worker_module>  
  StartServers          1  
  MinSpareThreads       1  
  MaxSpareThreads       5  
  ThreadLimit          64  
  ThreadsPerChild      25  
  MaxClients          150  
  MaxRequestsPerChild   0  
</IfModule>  


<IfModule mpm_event_module>  
  StartServers          1  
  MaxClients          150  
  MinSpareThreads      25  
  MaxSpareThreads      75  
  ThreadLimit          64  
  ThreadsPerChild      25  
  MaxRequestsPerChild   0  
</IfModule>
```

I typed site, then looked the request I made.There are only   (investigating with firebug) 9 file, but (ps aux | grep apache says) there are 4 apache processes running (one is mother).

```
root      1392  0.0  0.4  38452  8952 ?        Ss   Mar27   0:04 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start  
www-data 16407  0.0  0.6  43304 12316 ?        S    21:36   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start  
www-data 16408  0.0  0.5  43048 12192 ?        S    21:36   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start  
www-data 16644  0.0  0.2  38452  4244 ?        S    21:58   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start  
nerkn    16646  0.0  0.0   3204   884 pts/1    S+   21:58   0:00 grep --colour=auto apache
```

Can you suggest improvement?

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about it. The config you have is not going to eat your RAM. Note that the three www-data processes are forks, so they don't actually use that much extra memory if they are not serving data.